# Why Does Flow Proceed Even Though Required Fields Are Blank?

Tags: apex, visual-workflow

### Issue 1

I have a screen in my Flow with three required input components:

- Type (picklist)
- First Name (text)
- Last Name (text)

[image: Flow Screen Input Components]

However, I am able to click Next even if the required input components are blank. This is what I see in the Flow Builder's Debug mode when I do so:

[image: Flow Screen Issue]

### Issue 2

Sometimes the Flow displays a warning and prompts for the required fields to be populated. However, simply pressing the Next button again bypasses this warning and presents the same problem (as you can see in the screenshot above):

[image: Flow Screen Required Fields Warning]

### Additional Details

The screen:

- Is in a subflow.
- Contains components hidden by conditional visibility.
- Contains Aura and LWCs.

### Things I've Tried

- Activating the Flow and trying to run it outside of the Flow Builder - same issue occurs.
- Filling in one of the required fields, leaving the others blank, and clicking next - same issue occurs.
- Clicking into one of the required fields, then out of it, and clicking Next - the same issue occurs even though the Flow acknowledges the required field:

[image: Required Field Warning 2]

### Question

1. Why are these issues occurring?
2. Why doesn't Flow Builder's Debug mode highlight the problems?

Comment: Are those fields in particular just simply marked "required" in the flow screen setup? What is "next" after this screen? A LWC, another screen, etc.

Comment: @KrisGoncalves - Yes, the 'Require' checkbox on those input components is ticked. The immediate element after the screen is a decision. There are all kinds of elements after the decision - assignment, create, update, get, subflows (back in the master flow). Pressing next on the above screen performs a bunch of automations in the background and then takes the user to the next screen (which is a screen in the master flow).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up opening a case with Salesforce.

The case was escalated and their R&D team eventually confirmed that it is a bug. Bug Number: W-7124447.

Comment: Bug has now been fixed. Should be released in the next 10 days.

Comment: Excellent, thanks @AlexEdelstein. At this rate, looks you guys will be able to fix most, if not all, of the Flow-related bugs I reported before Spring '20 is released. Looking forward to the next Lightning Flow release readiness video. Keep up the great work!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a bug with Salesforce. It can be easily replicated by doing the following:

1. Create a screen based flow
2. Create a screen and drop on a Radio Buttons Control
3. Hook it up to a Picklist Choice Set that reads a picklist from an object(this is important as the bug only happens when reading choices from Salesforce and not when displaying choices created manually in the flow designer)
4. Mark the radio buttons as required
5. Create a second screen to ensure you have a next button on the first.
6. Link them all up, save, activate and Debug
7. Don't choose anything on the radio options, hit next and blank screen.

I will be posting a case with Salesforce later and will update this when I get a response.